# Asp.Net MVC 4 Web.Config Enable GZip Compression

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I test my MVC 4 website on GTMetrix performance tester. And says me, ENABLE GZIP COMP. for js and css contents. Then I write on this code in my web.config

```
    <system.webServer>
  <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\
temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
    <dynamicTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </staticTypes>
  </httpCompression>
  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

But not solve my problem. And I want to say, hosting isn't mine. I rent for 1 year to hosting company. So I can't reach IIS Manager.

Please help my problem, thank you.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the HTTP response headers for a JS or CSS file? Do you use MVC's bundling? Is this a release build? Did you upload the config?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k6j03oat4cw7j4j/Web.config   Yes, I'm using Bundling and release build

Comment: Yeah, you can see my test result,  http://gtmetrix.com/reports/satretex.windowsadair.com/e3dPJtmh   and my website satretex.windowsadair.com

Comment: How can i do this? Because I dont know what is fiddler.

Comment: See http://www.telerik.com/fiddler